firebase login with service account
I try to deploy a React app with GitLab CI/CD. With a token it worked, now I have to use a service account.
I defined a GitLab CI/CD variable $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_BASE64 with the content of the json and export it in the pipeline as documented, but I keep getting :

[2024-08-16T08:58:54.590Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2024-08-16T08:58:54.591Z] > authorizing via FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - main # Deploy only when changes are pushed to the main branch
  script:
    - echo "Starting deploy"
    - |
      if [ "$REACT_APP_ENV" == "preprod" ]; then
        npm install --location=global vercel
        cd src/riproaring
        vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
        vercel build --prod --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
        vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
      elif [ "$REACT_APP_ENV" == "prod" ]; then
        npm i -g firebase-tools
        cd src/riproaring
        echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_BASE64 > "./private-key.json"
        export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./private-key.json"
        # cat ./private-key.json
        echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
        firebase deploy --debug
      fi

I saw several posts in stackoverflow with similar problems but no suggestion worked. Vercel deploy still works without any issues.
Any ideas?
Thank you
Peter
I tried suggestions in other posts like:
text
or
text
But I always get the same error.
